# High Charts - dynamically place elements within tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to have High Charts dynamically place elements within its tooltip. To show you what I mean, imagine a tooltip like the one here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gn9zm/1/

What I'd like to do is have each label in the tooltip align with its corresponding point. I've looked at the formatter option, but it doesn't seem to give you a pixel location of the points. From searching around I've seen people refer to a toPixels method somewhere, but I can't seem to find it/access it from the scope within the formatter. Ideally I'm thinking my formatter would look something like this:

```
formatter: function() {
    return '<div style="position: absolute; top: '
           + toPixels(this.point.plotY) + 'px">' + p.y + '</div>';
```

Obviously this code would need to accommodate for the shared tooltip, but hopefully you get the idea. Is there a way I can accomplish what I'm seeking to do?

Answer (score 0):

In the formatter you need to use loop on each point (form points array) and then return correct values. In point object you have access to value in pixels by plotX/plotY parameters, so you don't need to call toPixels function.

http://jsfiddle.net/gn9zm/6/

```
formatter:function(){
        var points = this.points,
            txt = '';

        $.each(points,function(i,p){
            txt += ' value: ' + p.point.y + ' pixels: ' + p.point.plotY + '<br/>';
        });

        return txt;
    },
```

Comment: Awesome, this is helpful. I'm trying to place each individual point's text right next to the point itself. By using what you've demonstrated, it seems like I should be able to do this, but am unable to do so. Below is your fiddle updated with my attempt to move the text around based on their Y locations:  
http://jsfiddle.net/gn9zm/7/

Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean datalabels ?